# C equivalent of Python's regular expression

Tags: c, regex

I'm trying to check for a regex using c, but I don't know much about regex in c and can only come up with a pattern in Python.

Pattern would be: `STRING1.*?STRING2(STRING3)?STRING4`

I searched online and it seems like there are no good way to do it especially if I want it to be case insensitive.

There are some libraries, I guess, but I try to avoid that (can't say why. just know that there's a non-software reason behind it)

Would it work with `strstr`?

Comment: There's no standard library for pattern matching in C, although of course you can get one for many different platforms.

Comment: C does not have any built-in support for regex.  You will have to use a library if you want to stick with C.   C++  does have regexs. That may be helpful.

Comment: POSIX does have regex library, but the `*?` is not supported by POSIX

Comment: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/regex.h.html Not sure if all platforms support this but I just tested and mine has it.

Comment: Would the pattern still work in your use case if the `.*` was greedy?

Comment: I'm thinking about a workaround as well. What if I just go for `strstr` for `STRING1`, `STRING2`, `STRING3` and `STRING4` and ignore all the `?`? One problem is I want to do it caseless as well. I don't know if `toupper()` can do the job......

Answer (score 1):

There is a posix library for regular expression in C which might be of interest to you. This answer might help

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35887492/linux-c-replace-string-in-accordance-with-a-matching-rulesuch-as-any/35897946#35897946

Also go through this example of using posix library

[Posix regex example](http://www.peope.net/old/regex.html)

Other than this I don't think there is anything better available. Atleast I am not aware

Comment: You could improve your answer by including the important parts of your second link, reducing the risk of link-rot.

Answer (score 1):

One can use the [POSIX regexes](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/regcomp.html) commonly available, but POSIX regexes differ in significant ways from most other implementations such as Python, and will be lacking in a lot of modern features.

In C, and many other languages, one generally uses some implementation of [PCRE or Perl Compatible Regular Expressions](http://www.pcre.org/).  It will be closer to what's expected by a Python developer.  It's available as its own C library, or as [part of a larger C library such as Gnome Lib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Perl-compatible-regular-expressions.html).